# Gazebo Transport Messages: No standard messages for double, uint32, string, etc?

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It seems like the transport message types that come built-in with gazebo don't have any standard messages for things like a double, uint32, string, etc.  [I did manage to find one for an int32 under gazebo::msgs](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/d95058b6af43a01c5382a818da500a656206b145/gazebo/msgs/int.proto?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default), but that's it.  Am I somehow missing the rest?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/13147/gazebo-transport-messages:-no-standard-messages-for-double,-uint32,-string,-etc?/) by [pcdangio](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/257/pcdangio/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 207 on 2016-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

For string there is [GzString](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/d95058b6af43a01c5382a818da500a656206b145/gazebo/msgs/gz_string.proto?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default), and as you said there is one for [int32](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/d95058b6af43a01c5382a818da500a656206b145/gazebo/msgs/int.proto?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default). But I guess that's all.

For the other types you'd need to define custom messages, as explained [here](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials?tut=custom_messages&cat=transport).

---

Originally posted by [chapulina](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/1019/chapulina/) with karma: 7504 on 2016-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pcdangio](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/257/pcdangio/) on 2016-04-21**:
Yea I figured I'd have to make my own custom messages for the basic types.  If I can summon the energy, maybe I'll integrate them into gazebo::msgs and do a pull request.